# ¿Porqué no se realiza la migración de las tablas con php artisan migrate y solo migra una tabla en pHpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, migration, artisan

¡Buenas tardes!, tengo una base de datos en Mysql (PhpMyAdmin) que se llama proyectolaravel, pero mediante el editor Visual Studio Code en mi proyecto laravel tengo creado la clase de migración de la tabla Categorias con el comando php artisan make:migration create_categorias_table;

La clase migración de la tabla categorias:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('categorias')) {

            exit(0);
            
        } else {

            Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nombre',50)->unique();
                $table->string('descripcion',256)->nullable();
                $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
                $table->timestamps();
            });

        }
       
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categorias');
    }
}
```

También se creó la clase migración de la tabla productos con el comando php artisan make:migration create_productos_create;

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('productos')){

            exit(0);

        } else {

            Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('idcategoria')->unsigned();
                $table->string('codigo',50)->nullable();
                $table->string('nombre',100)->unique();
                $table->decimal('precio_venta',11,2);
                $table->integer('stock');
                $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
                $table->timestamps();
    
                $table->foreign('idcategoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
            });

        }
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('productos');
    }
}
```

Así también se creó la clase migración de la tabla proveedores en laravel con el comando php artisan make:migration create_proveedores_table;

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProveedoresTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('proveedores')){

            exit(0);
            
        } else {

            Schema::create('proveedores', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nombre',100)->unique();
                $table->string('tipo_documento',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('num_documento',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('direccion',70)->nullable();
                $table->string('telefono',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('email',50)->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });

        }
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('proveedores');
    }
}
```

Así mismo tengo creada la clase migración de la tabla clientes en laravel con el comando php artisan make:migration create_clientes_table;

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateClientesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('clientes')){

            exit(0);

        } else {

            Schema::create('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nombre',100)->unique();
                $table->string('tipo_documento',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('num_documento',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('direccion',70)->nullable();
                $table->string('telefono',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('email',50)->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });

        }
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('clientes');
    }
}
```

Así mismo tengo creada la clase migración de la tabla roles en laravel con el comando php artisan make:migration create_rol_table;

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('roles')){

            exit (0);

        } else{

            Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nombre',30)->unique();
                $table->string('descripcion',100)->nullable();
                $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
                //$table->timestamps();
            });
    
            DB::table('roles')->insert(array('id'=>'1','nombre'=>'Administrador','descripcion'=>'Administrador'));
            DB::table('roles')->insert(array('id'=>'2','nombre'=>'Vendedor','descripcion'=>'Vendedor'));
            DB::table('roles')->insert(array('id'=>'3','nombre'=>'Comprador','descripcion'=>'Comprador'));

        }
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

Y finalmente tengo creado la clase de migración de la tabla users en laravel con el comando php artisan make:migration create_users_table;

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schemma::hasTable('users')){

            exit(0);

        } else {

            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nombre',100);
                $table->string('tipo_documento',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('num_documento',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('direccion',70)->nullable();
                $table->string('telefono',20)->nullable();
                $table->string('email',50)->nullable();
                $table->string('usuario',80)->unique();
                $table->string('password',150)->unique();
                $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
                $table->integer('idrol')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('idrol')->references('id')->on('roles');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });

        }
       
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Pero en el momento de hacer la migración para crear las tablas en PhpMyAdmin (Maria DB) pero no se crearn las tablas mas que solo la tabla de categorias, en PHPMyAdmin, no lo se ¿cual es el problema que no se realiza la migración de las tablas? no se porque no se realiza, el comando de laravel que uso para la migración es:

php artisan migrate;

(pero no ejecuta la migración en PHP MyAdmin), su ayuda con este problema que tengo que no ejecuta la migración, ya que en cada clase valido que la tabla no esta creada para poder realizar la migración. ¡Gracias!

Comment: No te sale ningún error cuando haces la migración. Has probado hacer php artisan migrate:status para ver que sale. Has probado hacer php artisan migrate:refresh
Has probado hacer php artisan migrate:reset. Has probado hacer php artisan migrate --force // siempre que no tengas datos que perder. También que no se ejecuten en el orden que toca, e insertar valores una vez creada la tabla. Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo.

Comment: da f5 al phpMyAdmin

Comment: Estimado @JuanCarlosQuilesEstruch, ¡Buenas noches!; te saluda el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo desde Ecuador (Guayaquil) ya esta solucionado el problema de la migración que no realizada, simplemente ejecute el comando php artisan migrate:fresh para eliminar las tablas y volverlas a crear nuevamente, que se realizo correctamente.

Comment: Te comento que revertí tu edición, pues la respuesta no va en la pregunta, para eso puedes ocupar en la parte inferior la zona de respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

ya esta solucionado el problema de la migración que no realizada, simplemente ejecute el comando php artisan migrate:fresh para eliminar las tablas y volverlas a crear nuevamente, que se realizo correctamente

[image: Base de Datos Proyectolaravel - PhpMyAdmin]

Fuente de información:

[Laravel - Base de Datos (Migraciones)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations)